# Несколько маркеров в одной позиции (google.maps)

Tags: google-maps, javascript, php

Приветствую господа. Вот и пришло время задать мой первый вопрос.

У меня есть google карта на сайтике. На это карту, пользователям, разрешено добавлять новые маркеры. Но более чем вероятна ситуация добавления нескольких маркеров в одно и то же место. Сейчас если два маркера ссылаются на одно и то же место на карте то показывается последний из добавленных. Это не допустимо так как при клике на маркер появляется окошко с информацией. Но если показывается только последний добавленный маркер то и кликнуть, соответственно, можно только на него. А по всем остальным маркерам никак не получить информации потому, что они не отображаются(хотя может и отображаются но последний добавленный маркер их затирает). Я надеюсь я смог донести до вас свою проблему.

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы все добавленные маркеры отображались на карте. Была идея смещать маркер на один градус по широте или по долготе если он совпадает еще с каким то маркером. Но это жутко не хорошее решение. Не могли бы вы предложить какие-нибудь способы решения. Любые, даже самые абсурдные. Или может быть в гугл картах есть какие-нибудь встроенные решения этой проблемы.

Надеюсь на вашу помощь. Если что-то не ясно обязательно спрашивайте. Постараюсь изъясниться более ясно.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас два маркера в одной и той же позиции, то думаю можно свести это к отображению одного маркера, но вот само окно информации разбить на две части (как вариант: табы).

Таким образом можно отображать информацию об обоих маркерах. Для наглядности можно на этом одном  маркере еще отображать число - количество внесенных "мест" для данного маркера

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Решение с вкладками мне очень нравится. Только маркеров в одной позиции может быть на много больше двух. Если их будет хотя бы 10 то уже вкладки не будут выглядеть как следует красиво. Так что увы :(

Можно сделать ссылку вроде "здесь есть еще маркеры" и при клике на неё пользователя бы выкидывало на страницу с кратким описанием каждого маркера. Этот вариант мне, честно говоря, тоже нравится но буду держать его в запасе если ничего другого не найдется.

Еще раз спасибо Вам.

Comment: Еще вариант: можно вместо информационного окна сделать выезжающую панель справа на карте, которая будет занимать всю высоту карты. В этой панели будет список с информацией по всем маркерам. Если количество маркеров большое, то в панели можно добавить постраничный вывод. Таким образом в совместите оба решения. Ну и пользователю не нужно будет переходить на другую страницу и будет возможность перейти к следующему маркеру на карте

Comment: Отличный вариант. Принято :) 
Огромное спасибо!

Comment: не за что))